# Prettify bootstrap template from java spring

Tags: html, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I have a spring project focusing on library books that be checked out. Here is the html code rendered from the server side. The columns are crooked!

Here is the html code (and the first row):
https://pastebin.com/jz0ux8Dw

```
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Books</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
    <style>
        :root {
            --star-size: 30px;
            --star-color: #fff;
            --star-background: #fc0;
        }
 
        .Stars {
            --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: var(--star-size);
            font-family: Times;
            line-height: 1;
        }
        .Stars::before {
            content: "★★★★★";
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }
 
        .book{
            top:100px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
        }
        .book-link{
            position: relative;
            left:85%;
            top:100px;
            text-align: center !important;
        }
        .book-image{
            position: relative;
            left:50%;
            top: -15px;
        }
        .middle{
            position: relative;
            top:80%;
            left:90%;
        }
 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c436d239f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }
 
        li {
            float: left;
        }
        #container{
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
 
        /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }
 
        .item{
 
        }
        .desc{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .search-submit{
            font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
            font-weight: 900;
        }
        .search{
            position: absolute;
            float: right;
            top: 10px;
            right: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </li>
            <li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="wishlist">Wishlist</a></li>
            <li><a href="current">Current books</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recomended">Recomended</a></li>
            <li><a href="settings">Settings</a></li>
            <form class="search" action="/search">
                <input type="text" name="search_query">
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit"  value="&#xf002"/>
                </button>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
</body>
</html></div>
</div>
 
 
 
<div class="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 book">
           <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
               <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5704922109" class="book-link">High Achiever</a>
               <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5704922109">
                   <img src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781979830287/MC.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=" height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
                   <p  class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.94892"></p>
               </a>
           </div>
 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 book">
           <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
               <a href="https://rclreads.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1230417166" class="book-link">Craveable Keto Cookbook</a>
               <a href="https://rclreads.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1230417166">
                   <img src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781628602715/MC.GIF&amp;client=ramp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=" height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
                   <p  class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.92254"></p>
               </a>
           </div>
 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 book">
           <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
               <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5684947109" class="book-link">Fail Until You Don&#39;t</a>
               <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5684947109">
                   <img src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9780062795816/MC.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=" height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
                   <p  class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.91805"></p>
               </a>
           </div>
 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 book">
           <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
               <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5685848109" class="book-link">Believe Bigger</a>
               <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5685848109">
                   <img src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781501165672/MC.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=" height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
                   <p  class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.91794"></p>
               </a>
           </div>
 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: The columns are crooked]

I have tried bootstrap cards and using a bootstrap row but they are still not even.
Thank you for your assistance

Comment: It cannot be reproduced. Could you create [a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my issue. Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mx6sgru5/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have broken links to your CDN's. And some custom styles brake Bootstrap styles. Just remove them and all items greatly shown

[jsfiddle example can be seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/vorfh40c/1/)

An example:

```html
  <ul>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </li>
        <li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="wishlist">Wishlist</a></li>
        <li><a href="current">Current books</a></li>
        <li><a href="Recomended">Recomended</a></li>
        <li><a href="settings">Settings</a></li>
        <form class="search" action="/search">
          <input type="text" name="search_query">
          <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="&#xf002" />
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ul>




  <div class="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 book">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5704922109" class="book-link">High Achiever</a>
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5704922109">
            <img
              src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781979830287/MC.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc="
              height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
            <p class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.94892"></p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 book">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
          <a href="https://rclreads.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1230417166" class="book-link">Craveable Keto
            Cookbook</a>
          <a href="https://rclreads.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1230417166">
            <img
              src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781628602715/MC.GIF&amp;client=ramp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc="
              height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
            <p class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.92254"></p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 book">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5684947109" class="book-link">Fail Until You Don&#39;t</a>
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5684947109">
            <img
              src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9780062795816/MC.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc="
              height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
            <p class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.91805"></p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 book">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5685848109" class="book-link">Believe Bigger</a>
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5685848109">
            <img
              src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781501165672/MC.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc="
              height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
            <p class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.91794"></p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 book">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
          <a href="https://rclreads.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1203671166" class="book-link">Believe Bigger</a>
          <a href="https://rclreads.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1203671166">
            <img
              src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781501165672/MC.GIF&amp;client=ramp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc="
              height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
            <p class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.91794"></p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 book">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5685910109" class="book-link">The Pretty Dish</a>
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5685910109">
            <img
              src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781623369699/MC.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc="
              height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
            <p class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.91582"></p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 book">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
          <a href="https://rclreads.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1187373166" class="book-link">The Laura Lea Balanced
            Cookbook</a>
          <a href="https://rclreads.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1187373166">
            <img
              src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781940611563/MC.GIF&amp;client=ramp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc="
              height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
            <p class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.91263"></p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 book">
        <div class="card mb-3 box-shadow bg-light">
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5756079109" class="book-link">The Chapo Guide to
            Revolution</a>
          <a href="https://hclib.bibliocommons.com/item/show/5756079109">
            <img
              src="https://secure.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9781501187285/MC.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc=C.GIF&amp;client=hennp&amp;type=xw12&amp;oclc="
              height="200" width="130" class="card-img-top book-image">
            <p class="middle Stars" style="--rating: 4.9"></p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
```